# Nebensätze mit mehreren Pronomen, wie ist es korrekt?

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

Irgendwo habe ich diesen Satz gehört (aus einer deutschen Quelle, aber nicht auf Deutsch), und finde ich ihn wirklich interessant:

> *Die Menschen verhalten sich logisch **erst nachdem** sie alle andere Möglichkeiten schon ausgenützt haben.*

Mit Google-Translate und Googlen konnte ich diesen Satz als die beste deutsche Übersetzung konstruieren. Leider konnte ich die ursprüngliche Quelle in einer anderen Sprache nicht mit Google finden.

Die korrekte Reihenfolge der Pronomen ist hier ein bisschen kryptisch für mich; es gibt zu viele aufeinander gepackte Strukturen. Besonders *erst nachdem* + Nebensatz scheint mir problematisch. Es scheint mir, dass der Satz verständlich ist, aber kein Muttersprachler ihn so sagen würde.

Ist er verständlich? Woher könnte dieser Satz kommen?

Comment: '***alle ANDERE Möglichkeiten***' ??? Akkusativ Objekt ???

Comment: @mramosch Ja. "after they've depleted all of their alternatives", aber vielleicht ist es eben auf English problematisch. Warum wäre ein Objekt nicht in Akkusativ? "Ich stelle den Teller auf den Tisch". Teller ist das Objekt hier, und ist es in Akkusativ. Oder nicht?

Comment: @Jan Danke sehr!

Comment: Akkusativ ist absolut richtig aber dann müsste es '***alle andereN Möglichkeiten***' heißen... - Oder ohne 'alle' -> '*erst nachdem sie andere Möglichkeiten...*'

Comment: @mramosch Alle ist kein Adjektiv. Zum Beispiel, "zum unseren vollsten Zufriedenheit", eine gewöhnliche Phrase in den Arbeitszeugnisse, ist auch nicht korrekt, wie ich weiß, weil "voll" ist auch kein Adjektiv.

Comment: @mramosch Warte, das ist wie ich die Sachen weiß! Aber natürlich möchte ich es nicht besser wissen, als ein Muttersprachler :-) Wenn du es besser weißt, bitte erkläre es.

Comment: @mramosch Die perfekte Version nützt "alle" auch als Adjektiv! Etwas verstehe ich nicht.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Möglicherweise ist dieser Satz gemeint:

> Menschen nehmen nur dann die klügste Lösung, wenn alle anderen Gelegenheiten ausgeschöpft sind.

Das sagte der Astrophysiker [Harald Lesch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_Lesch) in seiner Sendung *alpha-Centauri* in der Ausgabe [*Was sind Wurmlöcher?*](http://www.br.de/mediathek/video/sendungen/alpha-centauri/alpha-centauri-wurmloecher-2001_x100.html) vom 23. Dezember 2001 (im Video ab 13:28).

Es wird an verschiedenen Stellen im Netz zitiert, häufig (etwa bei Wikiquote) allerdings mit dem Wort *Möglichkeiten* statt *Gelegenheiten*:

> Menschen nehmen nur dann die klügste Lösung, wenn alle anderen Möglichkeiten ausgeschöpft sind.

Comment: Ja! Das kam von einem Uni Gast-Professor, auch aus Bayern! Perfekt. Danke sehr!